# How to write and read array to file using WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have `int* arr = new int[n]`.

How I can write it to file `list.dat` with `WinAPI`? And how I can read it after writing?
upd: checkout tmy code pls: http://pastebin.com/eeMVk8JA

Comment: Call `WriteFile` to write, and `ReadFile` to read. Get the file handle with a call to `CreateFile`.

Comment: Wow, look - I've just googled your question and look what I've found! - http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/c/threads/31282/windows-api-functions-to-read-and-write-files-in-c . I wonder when did SO become new google search...

Comment: @zoska: That was pretty much by design. We close questions when there's a duplicate on SO, not when there's a duplicate elsewhere.

Comment: @MSalters, I understand, but there are questions which can be veeeryyy broadly understood and in these cases we mostly tell people - use this tutorial, check this documentation/manual. Nowadays it's very easy to find these things by yourself (as I described in my comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it depends on whether you're looking for something like a serialization, or if you just want to  emulate the standard C/C++ file manipulation with WinAPI.

Assuming the latter, look at the WinAPI file manipulation functions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232(v=vs.85).aspx